# Best practice: To clean or not to clean old branches

Tags: version-control

I've worked in different team and in one team people tend to clean the old branches as soon as they merge them. In other team branches stay forever. What is the benefit of deleting/keeping old branches? Does it depends on what source control system we use? (In my case - SVN).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer may be depended on the version control system that you use. For example, if you would use Git, then you should not try to remove any branch, since the branching system and the way commit and push history is handled (depended on branches) is way different than SVN.

In general, however, I tend to keep the old branches, and not delete them. And in professional places that I have worked, they tend to keep the branches too. In my point of view, keeping a branch not only provides you with code history, but also:

- Failed attempts history. You may later think about doing something that has failed before. If you keep the failed branch, you will be able to understand why it failed in the first place.
- Good reusable code may exist in these branches. Sometimes when the main stable branches ends discarding much code, good code developed for this branch specifically may end up in the trash, too. However, some of this code may prove useful in other situations in later stages of the development. So, why reinvent the wheel?
- Spinoff projects. In big projects, some times branches contain features that did not make it into the final product. From these features, there may be some new ideas that could form a standalone project by themselves.
- Proof. Let's face it, in companies, especially big ones, there are managerial concerns that need to be taken into account while committing code. For example, while looking at code history, you can immediately see who has committed faulty or good code, and avoid misunderstandings. I know it sounds cynical, but sometimes it saves people a lot of trouble.

In general, its History. Why delete branches that remind you of the paths that the development has followed up until now? I doubt it will have a significant impact on disk space (in most cases, at least. In other cases, it can have a big impact, but companies should take care of the problem of space before it actually becomes a concern). Branches represent thousands of man hours in terms of work. Deleting them is as if you throw this time away.

As far as discarding the branches, I cannot think of any reason other than to save space.

Answer (score 1):

Simple... You can back track as long as you want, if you have them.
In my case also it is SVN. I use to archive them by different tags and move it to a different folder. So always one hot folder (Live) with parallel dev branches, once merge is completed, go for archiving the branch.